# Forms Web Service: GetFormCollection Results Not Useful

Tags: web-services, forms-services

I'm trying to use the Forms Web Service, and specifically the [GetFormCollection operation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/forms.forms.getformcollection.aspx) to get the currently set forms for SharePoint lists.  Sadly, GetFormCollection seems to just kick back the default DispForm, NewForm, and EditForm aspx pages rather than reflecting the current form settings for the list.  This makes the GetFormCollection operation relatively useless in my eyes.

Anyone have any insights into this one?

M.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "answer" to this turns out to be the [Lists.GetListContentTypes Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/lists.lists.getlistcontenttypes.aspx) operation.  With it, you can get back the customized forms per Content Type.  I've added this operation into v0.4.8 of my [jQuery Library for SharePoint Web Services](http://spservices.codeplex.com) so that I can use it in the [SPScriptAudit](http://spservices.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=%24%28%29.SPServices.SPScriptAudit) function.

M.